# Generate definitions .d.ts with transpileModule

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript compiler API to generate js from ts.

My ts code is generated, so it's not saved in any file and i am using `transpileModule` to generate the js directly without needing to save a temporary ts file.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#transpiling-a-single-file

But i would like to have the option to generate `declarations` close to the js files.
I am passing `declaration` and `declarationDir` to compiler options but it does nothing...

```
export const defaultCompilerOptions: ts.CompilerOptions = {
  target: ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
  module: ts.ModuleKind.ES2015,
  lib: ['es2015'],
  strict: true,
  declaration: true,
  declarationDir: '/tmp/xpto',
};
const gen = ts.transpileModule(tsCode, { compilerOptions, fileName, reportDiagnostics: true });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate .d.ts from a js string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325695/how-to-generate-d-ts-from-a-js-string)

Answer (score 2):

You can't produce declaration files using `transpileModule` because this function only performs syntactic transformations (whereas declaration file emitting requires semantic information). You'll need to use the usual `createProgram` function shown at the top of that page.

Comment: So i need to save the files to a temporary ts file and then run the `createProgram` to do the generation?

Was trying to avoid to have to write the files, but if it has to be that way, no problem

Comment: @Porfírio you can!  see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70325695/how-to-generate-d-ts-from-a-js-string. I asked to merge the questions so people can see the correct answer without me copy/pasting.